# Unusual working hours and time off.

Tags: contracts, work-time, holidays

My working hours are 8:45-5:00 Monday to Thursday and 8:45-4:00 on Friday. I get 30 mins for lunch each day. My contract states my weekly working hours as 37hours and 45 minutes. I have been told we start 8:45 instead of 9 each mornning so we get to finish at 4 on friday. Now my question is:

If I take time off on friday why I have to use my full 1 day allowance instead of getting 1 hour back to my allowance because I already make up for that hour during the week? It seems very confusing to me.

Comment: This: `If I take time off on friday why I have to use my full 1 day allowance instead of getting 1 hour back to my allowance because I already make up for that hour during the week?` seems like a question for your employer honestly. In the company I work we take hours off, not days.

Comment: I suggest to adjust you attitude towards work-hours. Or maybe, if counting minutes is so important for you, look for a job that brings you more satisfaction.

Comment: @Daniel where in my question did I mention counting minutes is so important to me, and that my work doesn't bring me any joy?

Comment: You're quibbling over losing an hour.  Personally speaking, I wouldn't even raise it as an issue.

Comment: I am simply asking why it is that way. So your answers are not very helpful.

Comment: "why it is that way?" Because the people who made that rule thought it was a good idea.

Comment: It is that way because: just work a day, or take a day off. In any healthy work environment nobody cares if you did 9 hours yesterday and 7 today as long as you are able to perform your duties. If you think it is worth discussing the "lost" hour of your Fridays you are in fact counting the minutes (60 to be exact). Also you did not mention the +15 min´s you get for every non-Friday you take of. I don´t mean that in a bad way, just discovered that way of thinking leads to nothing. I loose more in traffic jams every month. solve that problem first!

Comment: Your seeming concern, *if I take leave Mon-Fri, I get 7 hr 45 min of leave, but if I decide to take leave on a Fri, I* only *get 6 hr 45 min of leave* can only be addressed by your company.

Comment: It's definitely less confusing and simpler to just let you take 1 day leave as opposed to letting you take 87% of a day's leave, or breaking days down into minutes. You lose an hour, but there's not much for you to do about that.

Answer (score 2):

Some companies give you 'the day off' regardless of how many hours you're actually in for that day; check with HR or your contract to see if you can take time off by the hour instead of the day. Similarly, a 'half-day' might be just taking midday-onwards off. It may vary depending on what country or industry you're in too. Best to check with your manager if the other sources don't help, though be careful it may come across as a little clock-watchy.

Early finishes are not so rare on Fridays. If you want your money's worth, it might be best to use Mondays for long weekends!